# 80s/90s movie: boys go missing at neighbor's house

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Looking for a 90s or 80s movie where 2 boys sneak out to go investigate the neighbor's house and they find a dungeon-like place in the basement. The neighbor may have been a vampire, I don't quite remember. The mom goes to save them. All I remember is the mom had very blonde hair in a pixie cut, and she had very bright blue eyes. I know it's not *Fright Night* or *The People Under the Stairs*. I don't think it's a very popular movie.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You're not sure if the neighbour is a vampire; do you remember any other fantasy elements in the movie?

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit of a long shot as it is actually a fairly popular cult classic film.  But could this be the 1987 film [*The Lost Boys*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Boys)?

Dianne Weist played the mom Lucy and had a pixie cut as in the following pic:

[image: Lucy, mom in Lost Boys]

You can also see her in [this clip on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kq3nRBxVD3k&list=PL45E762C65E05FA51&index=6):

I don't recall a dungeon per se.  But there were definitely vampires, young teen boys sneaking around and it was during the timeframe you mentioned.

Comment: I was _wondering_ about that, but didn't remember her as getting that involved.  But it's a really good answer.  (I don't recall a dungeon under a house, but the vampires' lair might qualify as dungeon-like.)

Comment: @davidW.  Thank you for the edits.  They look good.  Yes, the vampire lair in the derelict underwater hotel was what I was thinking of as well. Very dungeon like.  I also agree the mom (Lucy) character wasn't quite as heavily involved as Adria indicated.. But the pixie haircut really seemed to be on point which made me think it was worth suggesting even if only a longshot.

Comment: _When you're straaaange..._